# how to send extra data in sinch payload

Tags: android, push-notification, arrays, sinch

I'm using sinch SDK and I use gcm to send push notification, what I do is registering the user using the function `registerPushData (reg_id.getbytes ())`,the `reg_id` is the GCM registeration id but I want to send extra things like the user name and id.

I want to know how to do that and I also want to know the proper way to recieve them on the other side knowing that the function `registerPushData ()` is taking `byte[ ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass along extra data to your server however you like. Then, when making the request to GCM, it will look something like this:

`gcm.send(registration_id, options)`

Options is a JSON of whatever extra data you want to pass along. Example from Android docs:

```
{
  "registration_id" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
  "data" : {
    "Nick" : "Mario",
    "Text" : "great match!",
    "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark",
  },
}
```